# Too many DML rows: 10001(bulk update)

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am getting an error of Too many DML rows: 10001 on my batch class.I am putting up the code here consisting of both my scheduler class and batch class which is called through it.

**Scheduler Class :-**

```
global class PartnerLeadtoAccountScheduler implements Schedulable {
  global Database.Batchable<SObject> batchClass{get;set;}
  global Integer batchSize{get;set;} {batchSize = 200;}

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        PartnerLeadtoAccountBatch b = new PartnerLeadtoAccountBatch(); 
        //Parameters of ExecuteBatch(context,BatchSize)
        database.executebatch(b,200);
  }
}
```

**Batch Class :-**

```
global class PartnerLeadtoAccountBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global PartnerLeadtoAccountBatch(){
               // Batch Constructor
    }

    // Start Method
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     String query='Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null';
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

  // Execute Logic
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject>scope){
          // Logic to be Executed batch wise      


        map < Id, Account > mapAccount = new map < Id, Account > ();
        set < string > checkDuplicateEmail = new set < string > ();
        set < String > emailEntry = new set < String > ();
        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerLead = [Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null];
        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerLead1 = [Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null order by createddate asc];
        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();

        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName1 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt1 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();

        mapAccount = new Map < Id, Account > ([SELECT id, Subscription_Email__c, Channel_Partner__c, Closure_Source__c, RecordTypeId FROM Account]);
        for (account acc: mapAccount.values()) {
            checkDuplicateEmail.add(acc.Subscription_Email__c);
        }

        Map < String, Partner_Lead__c[] > assotiactedServiceByEmail = new Map < String, Partner_Lead__c[] > ();
        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerleadToBeUpdated = new List < Partner_Lead__c > ();
        List < Account > accountList = new List < Account > ();
        List < Account > updatedAccountList = new List < Account > ();        
        Map < string, Account > mapSAB = new Map < string, Account > ();
        Map < string, Account > mapUpdatedSAB = new Map < string, Account > ();
        set<string> emailString = new set<string>(); 
        map<string, Partner_Lead__c> partnerLeadMap = new map<string, Partner_Lead__c>();
        Partner_Lead__c plead;
        for (Partner_Lead__c pl: partnerLead) {
            plead = new Partner_Lead__c(id = pl.id);
            if (!checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)) {
                if(pl.Contact_Person__c!=null){
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.LastName = pl.Contact_Person__c;
                acc.RecordTypeId = rt;
                acc.Industry = pl.Business_Nature__c;
                acc.Company_Name__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                acc.Phone = pl.Contact_Number__c;
                acc.Designation__c = pl.Designation__c;
                acc.Subscription_Email__c = pl.Email_Address__c;
                acc.AccountSource = 'Channel Partner';
                acc.Channel_Partner__c = True;
                acc.Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                acc.CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                acc.Cp_Date__c = DateTime.valueOf(pl.createddate).Date();
                acc.CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;

                accountList.add(acc);                 
                }
            }
            if (checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)) {
                emailString.add(pl.Email_Address__c);
                partnerLeadMap.put(pl.Email_Address__c, pl);
            }
        }

        list<Account> accountUpdateList = [Select Id, Subscription_Email__c, RecordTypeId from Account where Subscription_Email__c in : emailString];
        for(account ac: accountUpdateList){
            Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName2 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
            Id rt2 = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();
            Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName3 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
            Id rt3 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();
            updatedAccountList.add(ac);
            if (mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c == 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt3) {
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c = 'Channel Partner';
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).OwnerId;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).Company_Name__c;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).Date__c;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).Package_Plan__c;
            } else if (mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c != 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt2) {
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).OwnerId;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).Company_Name__c;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).Package_Plan__c;
                mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = partnerLeadMap.get(ac.Subscription_Email__c).Date__c;
            }
        }

        List<Partner_Lead__c> pllist=new list<Partner_Lead__c>();
        if(accountList!=null){
            for (Account acc1: accountList) {
                mapSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
            }
        }
        for (Account acc1: updatedAccountList) {
            mapUpdatedSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
        }

        if (!mapSAB.values().isEmpty()) {
            insert mapSAB.values();          
        }        

        update mapAccount.values();

        //Populating Account lookup on partner lead object
        for(Partner_Lead__c pl :partnerLead){
            if(mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c)!=null){
                pl.Account__c=mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;               
            }
            else if(mapUpdatedSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c)!=null){
                pl.Account__c=mapUpdatedSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;                
            }                   
         pllist.add(pl);   
        }

        Integer cnt = 0;
        for (Partner_Lead__c pl: partnerLead1) {
            cnt++;
            plead = new Partner_Lead__c(id = pl.id);
            if (!(emailEntry.contains(pl.Email_Address__c))) {
                plead.Updated__c = true;
                emailEntry.add(pl.Email_Address__c);

            } else {
                plead.Conflict__c = true;
            }
            partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead);
        }

        update partnerleadToBeUpdated;
        update pllist;


   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        // Logic to be Executed at finish
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are updating all of your accounts in the code. Probably this line is causing the issue "update mapAccount.values();". You have to be selective here,

Comment: you are updating more then 10000 records in single DML thats not allowed. try to split them.

Comment: You should be off loading many of these queries to handler classes esp the record type queries.  I don't understand why you're querying Partner_Lead twice also

Comment: Also it's not your batch, your already breaking it down to 200 records per, it's something your doing after, put in System.debugs to figure out the break down

Comment: Can you please give a brief explanation on where I am lacking the right code, would be of great help.Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do to prevent this error:

1. Execute minimum no. of SOQL queries inside the `execute` method. And then add all possible filters in query to get minimum no. of records. After it make sure that you both list `partnerleadToBeUpdated` and `pllist` don't exceed `10000` size combined.
2. Another but not very reliable, reduce size of batch until to the limit when you stop getting 10001 error. Batch size can be reduced to `1` as:

   ```
   PartnerLeadtoAccountBatch b = new PartnerLeadtoAccountBatch(); 
   //Parameters of ExecuteBatch(context,BatchSize)
   database.executebatch(b,1);
   ```

But try to use maximum feasible size as per the batch design.

Nevertheless, you need to optimize your code because there are two many SOQL and for loops which are suspicious.